# How to copy and paste worksheets between Excel workbooks?

Tags: vba, excel

How do you transfer a worksheet from one excel app(1) to another(2) if you have two excel apps open using VBA?

The problem is, the programmer uses JavaScript, and when you click on the button that transfers the web data to a xl workbook, it opens a new Excel app.

I know part of the code would be:

```
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste    
' Once I returned to the original , i.e. excel app(1).
```

Answer (score 5):

Not tested, but something like:

```
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim destSheet As Worksheet

'' copy from the source
Workbooks.Open Filename:="c:\source.xls"
Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("source")
sourceSheet.Activate
sourceSheet.Cells.Select
Selection.Copy

'' paste to the destination
Workbooks.Open Filename:="c:\destination.xls"
Set destSheet = Worksheets("dest")
destSheet.Activate
destSheet.Cells.Select
destSheet.Paste

'' save & close
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Note that this assumes the destination sheet already exists. It's pretty easy to create one if it doesn't.

Comment: I had two Excel applications open.  WOuld this not just work if only one Excel applications  is open?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something with APIs.

```
Private Const SW_SHOW = 5
Private Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long

Function FindWindowPartialX(ByVal Title As String) As Long
    Dim hWndThis As Long
    hWndThis = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString)
    While hWndThis
        Dim sTitle As String, sClass As String
        sTitle = Space$(255)
        sTitle = Left$(sTitle, GetWindowText(hWndThis, sTitle, Len(sTitle)))
        sClass = Space$(255)
        sClass = Left$(sClass, GetClassName(hWndThis, sClass, Len(sClass)))
        If InStr(sTitle, Title) > 0 Then
            FindWindowPartialX = hWndThis
            Exit Function
        End If
        hWndThis = GetWindow(hWndThis, GW_HWNDNEXT)
    Wend
End Function

Sub CopySheet()
Dim objXL As Excel.Application

' A suitable portion of the window title such as file name '
WinHandle = FindWindowPartialX("LTD.xls")

ShowWindow WinHandle, SW_SHOW

Set objXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

objXL.Worksheets("Source").Activate
objXL.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy

Application.ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this code, hope this helps!

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim destination_wb As Workbook
Set destination_wb = Workbooks.Open(DESTINATION_WORKBOOK_NAME)

worksheet_to_copy.Copy Before:=destination_wb.Worksheets(1)
destination_wb.Worksheets(1).Name = worksheet_to_copy.Name
'Add the sheets count to the name to avoid repeated worksheet names error
'& destination_wb.Worksheets.Count


'optional
destination_wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

'I use this to avoid macro errors in destination_wb
Call DeleteAllVBACode(destination_wb)

'Delete source worksheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
worksheet_to_copy.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

destination_wb.Save
destination_wb.Close

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

---

```
' From http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/vbe.aspx           

Public Sub DeleteAllVBACode(libro As Workbook)
    Dim VBProj As VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As CodeModule

    Set VBProj = libro.VBProject

    For Each VBComp In VBProj.VBComponents
        If VBComp.Type = vbext_ct_Document Then
            Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
            With CodeMod
                .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
            End With
        Else
            VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
        End If
    Next VBComp
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just going to post the answer for python so people will have a reference.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from win32com.client import constants
import win32com.client

xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename_xls)
ws = xlWb.Worksheets(1)
xlApp.Visible=False
xlWbTemplate = xlApp.Workbooks.Open('otherfile.xls')
ws_sub = xlWbTemplate.Worksheets(1)
ws_sub.Activate()
xlWbTemplate.Worksheets(2).Copy(None,xlWb.Worksheets(1))
ws_sub = xlWbTemplate.Worksheets(2)
ws_sub.Activate()

xlWbTemplate.Close(SaveChanges=0)
xlWb.Worksheets(1).Activate()
xlWb.Close(SaveChanges=1)
xlApp.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code copies and pastes all sheets (not cell values) from one source workbook to a destination workbook:

```
Private Sub copypastesheets()

Dim wbSource, wbDestination As Object
Dim nbSheets As Integer

Set wbSource = Workbooks("your_source_workbook_name")
Set wbDestination = Workbooks("your_destination_workbook_name")
nbSheets = wbDestination.Sheets.Count - 1

For Each sheetItem In wbSource.Sheets

    nbSheets = nbSheets + 1
    sheetItem.Copy after:=wbDestination.Sheets(nbSheets)

Next sheetItem


End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also do this without any code at all. If you right-click on the little sheet tab at the bottom of the sheet, and select "Move or Copy", you will get a dialog box that lets you choose which open workbook to transfer the sheet to.

See [this link](http://www.officearticles.com/excel/copy_sheets_to_another_workbook_in_microsoft_excel.htm) for more detailed instructions and screenshots.

Answer (score -2):

To be honest I don't know that you can.  If you just set up a test instance and open Excel twice, because that is what you are talking about happening, if you name one workbook "test1" and another "test2" if you try to move a workbook, or even a worksheet between the two applications they are totally unaware of each other.  I also notice odd behavior while simply manually cutting and pasting from Excel instance 1 and Excel instance 2.

You may have to write two macros kind of a drop off and then a pick up from a location that you share between them.  Maybe a command button on the tool bar.

Maybe one of the super excel guys on here have a better answer.

Answer (score -2):

easiest way:

```
Dim newBook As Workbook  
Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=newBook.Sheets(1)
```

Comment: This solution doesn't take into account that there are two instances of excel in the users question.

Answer (score -2):

when you paste into Word, the formating/formula of excel still exists.  Simply click the clip board and select the option "keep text only."