# Macro to Copy data from specific sheet in many files in one folder to a consolidated file

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Excel macros.

I have a folder having many files.lets say A,B,C

They all have a worksheet named Summary.

I want a new file named Summary

Which iterates through each file and copies the summary worksheet...into separate worksheet in  summary file.

The summary file will hv 3 sheets named A,B, C each having its own summary

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try our search function in the upper right-hand corner. There are [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195566/copying-worksheets-from-one-excel-document-to-another), [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068110/importing-worksheets-into-one-excel-workbook), [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388715/how-to-copy-and-paste-worksheets-between-excel-workbooks), [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804914/excel-vba-to-copy-multiple-worksheets-into-one) [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881824/vba-loop-with-some-worksheets) questions.

Comment: Yes, [even more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840935/copy-set-of-worksheets-to-another-workbook)!

Comment: @Zairja the questions you have linked to are not similar to this one - this question is looking to work on multiple worbooks in a folder, not each sheet on a particular file. But yes, it has been asked many time before

Comment: possible duplicate of [Macro to loop through all sheets that are placed between two named sheets and copy their data to a consolidated file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470703/macro-to-loop-through-all-sheets-that-are-placed-between-two-named-sheets-and-co)

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need a list of files.  You can use another spreadsheet to hold the list, or you can scan the directory as follows:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fld = fso.GetFolder("C:\temp")
s = ""
For Each fil In fld.Files
   s = s & fil.Name & vbCrLf 'a sample of doing something with each fil
   'here you can open each workbook using Application.Workbooks.Open

   'then, or later, if you like you can close the ones you opened
   'by remembering which workbooks were opened before you started.
Next
```

-- See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242702%28v=vs.60%29

Next, you'll need to create a new workbook, which can be done using

```
Set newWkb = Application.Workbooks.Add()
```

-- See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff840478.aspx

Now you can use the techniques described by the above posters to copy the worksheet from one workbook to the new one.

For reference, here's some good information on the VBA language.  Check out the various Functions, Objects, and Methods, etc.. under the Language Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242702%28v=vs.60%29

And here's some good information about the Excel object model: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194068

Comment: Agree, but there is no actual question ;)